# The image of zero-measure set under normal mapping is Lebesgue measurable

Tags: real-analysis, convex-geometry, convexity, convex-analysis

Let $u$ be a convex function defined on a bounded open set $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $u$ is twice differentiable a.e. Let $E_u$ be the set on which $u$ is not twice differentiable. Then $E_u$ has zero Lebesgue measure. Let $T_u$ be the normal mapping of $u$.

Question: is $T_u(E_u)$ Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: How is the normal mapping defined?

Comment: $T_u(x):=\{p\in\mathbb{R}^n:u(z)\geq u(x)+\langle p,z-x\rangle,\forall\,z\in\Omega\}$.

Comment: Do you mean $T_u(x)=\partial u(x)$? i.e., $T_u(x)$ is the subgradient of $u$ at $x$? I am sure your set is Borel and that seems obvious, but a detailed proof might be annoying like all proofs that something nontrivial is Borel meausurable.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your comment.